# Combinations of two arrays with ordering in Julia

Tags: julia, combinatorics

If I have

```
a=[1,3,5,7,9]
b=[2,4,6,8,10]
```

and I want to create every combination of length 5 of the two lists with ordering.

So far I can get every possible combination through:

```
ab=hcat(a,b)
collect(combinations(ab,5))
```

but I want to receive only the 32 (in this case) ordered combinations.

A function similar to what I am looking for would be the Tuples[Transpose@{a,b}] function in Mathematica.

EDIT:
Mathematica output would be as follows

```
a = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
b = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
combin = Tuples[Transpose@{a, b}]
Length[combin]

Out[1]:= {{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {1, 3, 5, 7, 10}, {1, 3, 5, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 5, 8,
10}, {1, 3, 6, 7, 9}, {1, 3, 6, 7, 10}, {1, 3, 6, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 6,
8, 10}, {1, 4, 5, 7, 9}, {1, 4, 5, 7, 10}, {1, 4, 5, 8, 9}, {1, 4,
5, 8, 10}, {1, 4, 6, 7, 9}, {1, 4, 6, 7, 10}, {1, 4, 6, 8, 9}, {1,
4, 6, 8, 10}, {2, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {2, 3, 5, 7, 10}, {2, 3, 5, 8,
9}, {2, 3, 5, 8, 10}, {2, 3, 6, 7, 9}, {2, 3, 6, 7, 10}, {2, 3, 6,
8, 9}, {2, 3, 6, 8, 10}, {2, 4, 5, 7, 9}, {2, 4, 5, 7, 10}, {2, 4,
5, 8, 9}, {2, 4, 5, 8, 10}, {2, 4, 6, 7, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 7, 10}, {2,
4, 6, 8, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}}

Out[2]:= 32
```

Comment: Are you sure about the 32 ? I mean, If I understood correctly, you're trying to get all the combinations x1,x2,x3,x4,x5 where x1<x2<x3<x4<x5 right ? To get these combinations , I used  `filter(x->issorted(x),collect(combinations(ab,5)))`  but it returns 26 ?

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally posted my comment to your post on @Matt B. 's post.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: Probably the fastest and memory minimal solution, which also uses generators à la 0.5 : `([ifelse(((i>>j)&1)==0,a,b)[j+1] for j=0:4] for i=0:31)`. `collect` this line to get the array, but the generator is probably the needed construct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a v0.5 solution using `Base.product`.

With

```
a = [1,3,5,7,9]
b = [2,4,6,8,10]
```

To create an array of tuples

```
julia> vec(collect(Base.product(zip(a, b)...)))
32-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64,Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1,3,5,7,9) 
 (2,3,5,7,9) 
 (1,4,5,7,9) 
 (2,4,5,7,9) 
 (1,3,6,7,9) 
 (2,3,6,7,9) 
 (1,4,6,7,9) 
 (2,4,6,7,9) 
 (1,3,5,8,9) 
 (2,3,5,8,9) 
 ⋮           
 (2,4,6,7,10)
 (1,3,5,8,10)
 (2,3,5,8,10)
 (1,4,5,8,10)
 (2,4,5,8,10)
 (1,3,6,8,10)
 (2,3,6,8,10)
 (1,4,6,8,10)
 (2,4,6,8,10)
```

and to collect that result into a matrix

```
julia> hcat((collect(row) for row in ans)...)
5×32 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  …   2   1   2   1   2   1   2   1   2
 3  3  4  4  3  3  4  4  3  3  4  4  3      4   3   3   4   4   3   3   4   4
 5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  5  5  5  5  6      6   5   5   5   5   6   6   6   6
 7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8      7   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8
 9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9     10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
```

Comment: That's nice : )

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! Thanks again @zwlayer and Fengyang

Answer (score 4):

There is a package [Iterators.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Iterators.jl). By using it (First you should install it by `Pkg.add("Iterators")`) you can do the following:

```
using Iterators
for p in product([1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10])
           @show p
end
```

Output:

```
p = (1,3,5,7,9)
p = (2,3,5,7,9)
p = (1,4,5,7,9)
p = (2,4,5,7,9)
p = (1,3,6,7,9)
p = (2,3,6,7,9)
p = (1,4,6,7,9)
p = (2,4,6,7,9)
p = (1,3,5,8,9)
p = (2,3,5,8,9)
p = (1,4,5,8,9)
p = (2,4,5,8,9)
p = (1,3,6,8,9)
p = (2,3,6,8,9)
p = (1,4,6,8,9)
p = (2,4,6,8,9)
p = (1,3,5,7,10)
p = (2,3,5,7,10)
p = (1,4,5,7,10)
p = (2,4,5,7,10)
p = (1,3,6,7,10)
p = (2,3,6,7,10)
p = (1,4,6,7,10)
p = (2,4,6,7,10)
p = (1,3,5,8,10)
p = (2,3,5,8,10)
p = (1,4,5,8,10)
p = (2,4,5,8,10)
p = (1,3,6,8,10)
p = (2,3,6,8,10)
p = (1,4,6,8,10)
p = (2,4,6,8,10)
```

**EDIT**

To get the results as array of arrays or matrix you can do :

```
arr = Any[]
       for p in product([1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10])
                  push!(arr,[y for y in p])
       end
    # now arr is array of arrays. If you want matrix:
    hcat(arr...)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to get the results as an array of arrays or matrix?

Comment: Another way with Iterators package is `map(x->[a[x];b[setdiff(1:5,x)]],subsets(1:5))`. It outputs an array. `setdiff` is supposed to be slow though. But it is readable enough.

Comment: @AlejandroBraun see my edit and please accept the answer if it is okey for you

Comment: I will double check it once I am back on my computer, had a late meeting so I didn't get to check stackexchange.

Comment: @zwlayer This gives me the desired result, but it involves separating the arrays into the [1,2],[3,4] format. This calculation will be one of a string of calculations, as such I will need to find a way to automatically convert ab into the [1,2],[3,4] format. Thank you for all the help you have provided!

Comment: @AlejandroBraun yes you're right, Wang's solution is more flexible and easier than mine. You're welcome! : )

Comment: this solution still works, but Iterators.jl is deprecated use IterTools instead

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution is to simply filter out the unsorted elements; `filter(issorted, …)` should do the trick.  This yields 26 elements, though, so perhaps I'm misunderstanding your intention:

```
julia> collect(filter(issorted, combinations(ab,5)))
26-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1,3,5,7,9]
 [1,3,5,7,8]
 ⋮
```

Comment: Almost at the same time :)

Comment: I am sure it should be 32. I think we are answering two different questions. The output I am looking for would not contain [1,3,5,7,8] as the element in, for example position 5, would only be able to contain an element that is in position five of one of the arrays included in the combination. Therefore, there could be [1,3,5,7,9] and [1,3,5,7,10] but not [1,3,5,7,8] as "8" would be coming from position 4 of one of the arrays.

Comment: I will post the output from Mathematica into the main question section to show what I am looking for.

Comment: Ah, of course; `combinations` doesn't preserve the ordering and there is no distinction between the two columns.  It's not doing what you want in your example.